# Kubernetes access Service in other namespace via http request

Tags: kubernetes

I've got an InfluxDB as database service in the **default** namespace.
It's service is called influxdb and works fine with chronograf to visualize the data.

Now i'd like to connect with an other deployment from the namspace **test** to this service. It's a python application. The normal python Influxdb Lib uses [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) to connect to the db.

**Architecture Overview**

Istio is also installed.

Namspace: Default

- Influxdb Deployment
- Influxdb Service
- Chronograf Deployment (visualise influxdb)
- Chronograf Service to Ingress(for external web access)

Namespace: test

- Python App which should connect to influxdb for processing etc.
- Influxdb Service (which points to influxdb.default.svc.cluster.local)

Therefore i created a **service** in the Namespace **test** which points to the service of influxdb in the default namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: influxdb
  labels:
    app: pythonapp
  namespace: test
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: influxdb.default.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
    - port: 8086
      name: http
    - port: 8088
      name: http-flux
```

And now deployed the python app which points to the influxdb Service. Which keeps getting a http connection error.

```
2020-07-03 13:02:05 - db.meterdb [meterdb.__init__:57] - ERROR - Oops, something wen't wrong during init of db. message: HTTPConnectionPool(host='influxdb', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /query?q=SHOW+DATABASES (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6863ed6310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
2020-07-03 13:02:05 - db.meterdb [meterdb.check_connection:113] - ERROR - can't reach db server... message: HTTPConnectionPool(host='influxdb', port=8086): Max retries exceeded with url: /ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6863e57650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

When I visualise the traffic with kiali I see, that the Python app tries to connect to the influxdb service, but which is unknown with http traffic.

I don't know how to get it work to use the created influxdb Service.

Connection settings for python influxdb Client library. [Link to python influxdb lib](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python)

- host=influxdb
- port=8086

[Traffic from Kiali](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjXQu.png)

How can i route the traffik to the right service ?
It seems to me, that it routes the traffik to an unknown service because it's http and not tcp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: influxdb
  labels:
    app: pythonapp
  namespace: test
```

Just access the service directly in your python request:

```
requests.get('influxdb.default.svc.cluster.local:8086')
```

And this can be more configurable.

```yaml
# Kubernetes deployment
      containers:
      - name: pythonapp
        env:
        - name: DB_URL
          value: influxdb.default.svc.cluster.local:8086
```

```py
# python
DB = os.environ['DB_URL']
requests.get(DB)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this solved my problem.
Leave the Service away and directly point to the influxdb in the default namespace.